# Linq To SQL: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Why do I get compilation errors from the following?

```
int[] threadIDs = { 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 };
CSDataContext db = new CSDataContext();
var posts = from p in db.cs_Posts, t in threadIDs
    where p.ThreadID == t
    select p.ThreadID;
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Select all posts that have thread IDs in the list?

Then something like this would work

```
int[] threadIDs = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
CSDataContext db = new CSDataContext();
var posts = from p in db.cs_Posts
    where threadIds.Contains(p.ThreadID)
    select p.ThreadID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you Try

```
var posts = from p in db.cs_Posts
            from t in threadIDs
            where p.ThreadID == t
            select p.ThreadID;
```

Leave out the comma and add another 'from'

Comment: This won't work if it is linq to sql, as is tagged in the question.

Comment: Your answer got rid of my compilation errors but as John Gietzen mentioned, it wont work if it is in linq to sql. Nice try and thanks!